# How to Calculate Median Function in Azure Data Flows?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I am trying do median on the numeric column in the aggregate transform, but i am unable to find median function.

How can I solve Median in azure data flows

Comment: Can you please add additional information like what you have tried. Also provide a sample input and expected output.

Comment: i have a salary column with values 100,200,300,400,500,600 i need median of these values

Another example is for numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 median is 4. how to get that using azure data transformations group by class or school

Comment: https://mssqldude.wordpress.com/2020/05/13/median-function-in-azure-data-factory/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get median of numeric value, first we have to use collect() function within the aggregate so that we may have an index for each value to locate the center and a count() function to keep track of how many indexes there are present in column.

[image]

After that in derived column activity create a median column and defined formula using columns created in aggregate activity.

**If length of column is odd**

```
salarycollection[toInteger(round(salarycount+1)/2)]
```

[image]

**If length of column is even**

```
(salarycollection[toInteger(round(salarycount+2)/2)]+salarycollection[toInteger(round(salarycount)/2)])/2
```

[image]

***My sample data***

[image]

***Output***

***for odd***
[image]
***for even***
[image]